# Kafka Guaranteed processing order - Consumers down

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to design messaging module addressing this scenario.
There are 100s of producers that produce messages to Kafka and several distributed consumers listen to the topics and process. However, there is a chance that due to some anomaly all consumers can go down and by the time they woke up, there are 1 million messages on several topics.

1. How can the processing order of the messages be guaranteed when several consumers try to process different messages off of a partition?
2. The messages must be processed in the ascending order of posted time to satisfy the use case, meaning M1 must be processed first, next M2, M3 and so on. If all consumers, C1...Cn wake up the same time, how can it be ensured that message M2 will not be processed by consumer C2 until M1 is processed by, say, C1; that is, processing by the order of offset?
3. Are there any Kafka configs at topic, partition, or consumer levels that address this issue?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

> several consumers try to process different messages off of a partition

That's not possible. Only one consumer in a consumer group can be assigned and read one partition.

> messages must be processed in the ascending order of posted time

Kafka only guarantees processing of offset order, not timestamp order. As an example, your producer tries to send a batch of records, but has a network delay, and another producer completes its writes first while having "later generated" events (as compared to the first producer). The consumer will then process those "later" events before the first "delayed producer" completes its write.

If you need time-based processing, then processing data from the Kafka Consumer API is not going to work; you'll need to batch your data somewhere else (e.g. a database), then order by timestamp, and then process in that order. Or you need to rewrite your data models such that time-ordering is really not important (any new event you get acts entirely as an update/overwrite). Otherwise, you need to store data persistently as it's processed, then query that store on every new incoming messages to say if that particular event has already been processed - or if event-timestamp is greater than some "last updated" field, then continue processing, else skip.